# stackexchange.com portal "Hot Questions" time doesn't have any UTC time stamp

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, tooltips, timestamps, homepage

On the [front page hot questions](https://stackexchange.com/), there is no UTC time stamp:

<kbd>[image: no time stamp image]</kbd>